# Laravel Using ->lists() on Non-Eloquent Models

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent, laravel-5

For reasons of database complexity, I'm running queries in a Laravel project without using a Model for each table. What I'm trying to accomplish is retuning the same results Laravel's `->lists("column_1", "column_2", "...")` would. Basically, I am querying a table, joining it to four other tables, and outputting the results in a table.

Here is an example of the query I'm trying to run to get my results:

```
DB::connection("example")->select(DB::raw("SELECT table_1.name, table_2.name FROM table_1 LEFT JOIN table_2 ON table_2.table_1_id = table_2.id WHERE table_2.status = 'something';"));
```

Basically, I'm trying to convert this to eloquent using the following chained query:

```
DB::connection("example")
  ->table("table_1")
  ->leftJoin("table_2", "table_2.table_1_id", "=", "table_1.id")
  ->lists("table_1.name", "table_2.name")
  ->where("table_2.status", "=", "something");
```

What this *should* do is return the unique values in both `table_1`'s `name` column, and `table_2`'s `name` column. However, Laravel returns the following error:

> Integrity constraint violation: 1052 Column 'name' in field list is ambiguous: SELECT `name`, `name` FROM table_1 LEFT JOIN table_2 ON table_2.table_1_id;

Now I know there is an ambiguity issue, which is why I put `->lists("table_1.name", "table_2.name")`, but Laravel seems to ignore this.

Does anyone know how I would return a list of the unique values in each column **using Laravel**? I think I can write a `SELECT DISTINCT(table_1.name), DISTINCT(table_2.name), ...` for each one, and I will do that as a last resort.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found a usable Laravel solution that doesn't use lists, but accomplishes the same thing. First, I prepare the query without the `->lists()` closure:

```
$query = DB::connection("example")
  ->table("table_1")
  ->leftJoin("table_2", "table_2.table_1_id", "=", "table_1.id")
  ->where("table_2.status", "=", "something");
```

Then, add a `->select(...)->get()` closure to the `$query` object for each column I need the values of:

```
$table_1_names = $query->select("table_1.name" AS "Table 1 Name")->distinct()->get();
$table_2_name = $query->select("table_2.name" AS "Table 2 Name")->distinct()->get();
```

Calling `dd()` on either of those variables returns an array of all the unique values in that specific column, which can be used in a `foreach` loop in a view.

Comment: In Laravel 5.3 `lists` will be deprecated. It has been renamed to `pluck`. Method signature is the same.

Answer (score 0):

I think this can be solved by using an alias in the select statement:

```
 DB::connection("example")->select(DB::raw("SELECT table_1.name AS name, ...)
```

Then you can use the alias in the ->lists(name)

http://forumsarchive.laravel.io/viewtopic.php?id=8730

Comment: Unfortunately I have tried this, running `->lists()` on my `$report = DB::connection("example")->select(DB::raw(...))->lists(...);` but it returns the error: `Call to a member function lists() on a non-object`. I think it has something to do with not using `->table(...)`, but I'm really not sure.

Comment: Do you need to use DB::connection?

Comment: Yes I do. My set-up doesn't have a default database, but can connects to four different ones, so I do need to specify the connection. But I don't think that would make a difference.